# How to enable header_position in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

In versions prior to TYPO3 7.6 you could select a position for your header within your content element (left, middle, right as far as I remember).

The field which has been used for storing that information in tt_content `header_position` is still available.

However, it will not appear in the backend. 
I'm also using `fluid_styled_content` for rendering my content, and the Header partial doesn't contain any reference to the position, but only to the layout field.

My question is: How can I reenable that field and use it to position my headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build a quick extension of yours which can reenable the field. You need to create folders and a file like following:
*your_ext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php*
the contents of that file are:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility;
ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content',[
    'header_position' => [
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tt_content.header_position',
            'config' => [
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                    'items' => [
                            ['LLL:EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tt_content.header_position.left', 'left'],
                            ['LLL:EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tt_content.header_position.right', 'right'],
                            ['LLL:EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tt_content.header_position.center', 'center']
                    ]
            ]
    ]   
]);

ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette('tt_content', 'header', '--linebreak--,header_position', 'after:header_layout');

ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette('tt_content', 'headers', '--linebreak--,header_position', 'after:header_layout');
```

Now the field should be back in the backend, because you've added it to the TCA via **addTCAColumns** to the **tt_content** configuration and added it via **addFieldsToPalette** to the **header** and **headers** palettes of **tt_content**, which are used by the types **textmedia** and **header**.
You can find out more about this by using the Configuration module in the TYPO3 backend. You can see it, when you are logged in as admin. Also a good place to look and learn about the TCA is the TCA reference: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/

Now you need to alter the **fluid_styled_content** templates. You need to create template overrides for the header partial of **fluid_styled_content**.

First create a folder: *your_ext/Configuration/TypoScript* and add a *setup.txt* and a *constants.txt* file. 
In *setup.txt* add the following lines:

```
lib.fluidContent{
    templateRootPaths{
         10 = {$plugin.your_ext.view.fluid_styled_content.templateRootPath}
    }
    partialRootPaths{
         10 = {$plugin.your_ext.view.fluid_styled_content.partialRootPath}
    }
    layoutRootPaths{
        10 = {$plugin.your_ext.view.fluid_styled_content.layoutRootPath}
    }
}
```

In *constants.txt* do:

```
plugin.your_ext{
    view{
        fluid_styled_content{
            templateRootPath = EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/FluidStyledContent/Templates/
            partialRootPath = EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/FluidStyledContent/Partials/
            layoutRootPath = EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/FluidStyledContent/Layouts/
        }
    }
}
```

To enable your TypoScript, you need to add a ext_tables.php in your your_ext folder and give it the following one-liner:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY,'Configuration/TypoScript', 'Your Ext Template');
```

You need to include your static TypoScript to your page via the Template module to enable the change to **fluid_styled_content**

Now you can copy the templates you need from

*typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Templates*

*typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials*

*typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts*

into your extensions folders you need to create:

*your_ext/Resources/Private/FluidStyledContent/Templates*

*your_ext/Resources/Private/FluidStyledContent/Partials*

*your_ext/Resources/Private/FluidStyledContent/Layouts*

Now you can alter the templates. For your **header_position** field, you probably just need to copy

*typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/Heaeder.html*

to

*your_ext/Resources/Private/FluidStyledContent/Partials/Header.html*

and add your selected value as **{data.header_position}** to a div class and style that.

Keep in mind you do not need to copy all of the templates, because with the TypoScript you just defined another location for **fluid** to search for templates and take them, if they are available. If not, **fluid** will walk back the chain and take the templates that are defined at position 9 and lower. You can look into the **TypoScript Object Browser** by the Template module and look into the TypoScript variable **lib.FluidContent** to see, if your TypoScript include has worked.

Hope this helped a bit ;)

Answer (score 3):

The database field `header_position` is only included in the TYPO3 core extension `css_styled_content`. If you don't have that extension installed the field in the database is probably there because it was installed sometime before.

It is not advised to install css_styled_content and fluid_styled_content installed in parallel as some options can conflict.

If you want to use fluid_styled_content and have the `header_position` field available the best way to go would be to create a very small TYPO3 extension yourself that includes the necessary SQL definition for the column `header_position`, the appropriate TCA configuration for that column and a few bits of TypoScript to extend/override the „Partial” paths of fluid_styled_content.